# Is it possible to access all Tweets from a user using the Twitter API?

Tags: twitter

The Twitter REST API 1.1 documentation for the [`GET statuses/user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) method states:

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user's most recent Tweets. Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in this total, regardless of whether include_rts is set to false when requesting this resource.

Does this mean one can only traverse the 3,200 newest tweets form a user's timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean one can only traverse the 3,200 newest tweets form a user's timeline?

Yes, though nothing is stopping you from caching tweets yourself.